# AssetImage not showing in card of a staggered grid list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

`AssetImage` is not showing in the card for my all-in-one social media app (by launching URL), which I am creating by using a staggered grid.

I made a list of large grid tiles and a list of `images(data type: 'widget')`.

I also created a class of `TileDesign` and a constructor with properties `Color`,  `backgroundColor` and `AssetImage`.

[staggered grid list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/900YY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below before that please check assets setting 
You can put your Asset Images in assets directory. In your code you put it in `lib` 
and In your pubspec.yaml , set the following , see image below

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

[image]

Assume your TileDesign work correctly. You did not post that part, so I use mine.

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Example01(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

List<StaggeredTile> _staggeredTiles = const <StaggeredTile>[
  const StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  const StaggeredTile.count(2, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(3, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(4, 1),
];

List<Widget> _tiles = const <Widget>[
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.green, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.lightBlue, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.amber, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.brown, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.deepOrange, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.indigo, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.red, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.pink, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.purple, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
  const _Example01Tile(Colors.blue, AssetImage('assets/images/person.png')),
];

class Example01 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('example 01'),
        ),
        body: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
            child: new StaggeredGridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              staggeredTiles: _staggeredTiles,
              children: _tiles,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            )));
  }
}

class _Example01Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Example01Tile(this.backgroundColor, this.assetImage);

  final Color backgroundColor;
  final AssetImage assetImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: new Center(
          child: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child:Image(image: assetImage)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so this is working correctly but my images are not of the same size as are in yours. What should I do now?

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps .You can click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. For your second question. please post your TileDesign code.

Comment: try this to fill your image.     return new Card(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child:  Container(
          //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          //height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: assetImage,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );